# XAML autocomplete tags doesn't work as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml, autocomplete, editor, visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2017 XAML editor, if i have a full tag

```
<myTag></myTag>
```

and i want to convert it to simple tag (without the closing tag), i would simply position the cursor at position 7 and insert the '/' character. Xaml editor will then produce the following output:

```
<myTag />
</myTag>
```

which is obviously wrong. This used to work correctly in previous versions, the expected result is:

```
<myTag />
```

I tried changing the XAML Text Editor settings in Visual Studio Options, but without success.

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: I can recall that this works in VS2015 with ReSharper. But maybe this is a Resharper function?

Comment: Just tested it and it does work with default settings in VS2017.

Comment: @jHilscher  Maybe my xaml editor bugs up for some reason, i have multiple VS2017 open, and even VS2015 at the same time. Sometimes it works correctly, but mostly it doesn't. Like right now, i have multiple xaml views open in tabs, in one view it works fine, in the other it doesn't. Annoying sneaky bug, this.